# Code causing content page content to disappear

Tags: php

The code below is causing the page I am working on to return a blank page.  There is other code on the page that is supposed to return content, and it does if I comment out the code below.  Are there any errors in the code below?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
$querysub = mysql_query("SELECT subcheck FROM submission WHERE submissionid = $submissionid");
$result = mysql_query($querysub);
if (!$result) {
    die 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
}
else{
$subcheck = mysql_result($result, 0);
}

if($uid = $submittor)
{

if($subcheck = 1)
{

echo '<div class="commentnotify">You submitted item story and you have chosen to receive emails when someone comments on it.<a href="http://www...com/.../comments/commentnotifystop.php?submission='.urlencode($row["title"]).'&submissionid='.$row["submissionid"].'&url='.$row["url"].'&countcomments='.strtoupper($row["countComments"]).'&submittor='.$row["username"].'&submissiondate='.$row["datesubmitted"].'&dispurl='.$row["displayurl"].'">Click here to stop.</a></div>';


} else {
   echo '<div class="commentnotify">You submitted this item and you have chosen not to receive emails when someone comments on it.<a href="http://www...com/.../comments/commentnotifystart.php?submission='.urlencode($row["title"]).'&submissionid='.$row["submissionid"].'&url='.$row["url"].'&countcomments='.strtoupper($row["countComments"]).'&submittor='.$row["username"].'&submissiondate='.$row["datesubmitted"].'&dispurl='.$row["displayurl"].'">Click here to start.</a></div>';


} else {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying assignment operator `=` in your `if` conditions, you need [comparison operator](http://php.net/language.operators.comparison) (`==`) instead:

```
if($uid = $submittor)
```

Should be:

```
if($uid == $submittor)
```

And

```
if($subcheck == 1)
```

You are also missing closing bracket `}` after this line:

```
echo '<div class="commentnotify">You submitted this item and you have chosen not to receive emails when someone comments on it.<a href="http://www...com/.../comments/commentnotifystart.php?submission='.urlencode($row["title"]).'&submissionid='.$row["submissionid"].'&url='.$row["url"].'&countcomments='.strtoupper($row["countComments"]).'&submittor='.$row["username"].'&submissiondate='.$row["datesubmitted"].'&dispurl='.$row["displayurl"].'">Click here to start.</a></div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two `else` blocks. But I guess it is just a problem with the nesting in this case:

```
if($uid = $submittor)
{
    if($subcheck = 1)
    {
        echo '<div class="commentnotify">You submitted item story and you have chosen to receive emails when someone comments on it.<a href="http://www...com/.../comments/commentnotifystop.php?submission='.urlencode($row["title"]).'&submissionid='.$row["submissionid"].'&url='.$row["url"].'&countcomments='.strtoupper($row["countComments"]).'&submittor='.$row["username"].'&submissiondate='.$row["datesubmitted"].'&dispurl='.$row["displayurl"].'">Click here to stop.</a></div>';
    } else {
       echo '<div class="commentnotify">You submitted this item and you have chosen not to receive emails when someone comments on it.<a href="http://www...com/.../comments/commentnotifystart.php?submission='.urlencode($row["title"]).'&submissionid='.$row["submissionid"].'&url='.$row["url"].'&countcomments='.strtoupper($row["countComments"]).'&submittor='.$row["username"].'&submissiondate='.$row["datesubmitted"].'&dispurl='.$row["displayurl"].'">Click here to start.</a></div>';

    }  // <-- added this one
} else {

}
```

By the way: You are using the [assignment operator](http://php.net/language.operators.assignment) `=` instead of an [comparison operator](http://php.net/language.operators.comparison) like `==`. And an assignment operator yields the assigned value. So the expression `$uid = $submittor` returns the value of `$submittor` and `$subcheck = 1` returns `1`.

Answer (score 0):

It's missing the last bracket of if($uid = $submittor) { ... }. Then you're getting an error, but your server seems not able to show them, displaying a blank page.